# Runtime shows mapper class not found exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

map 0% reduce 0%
15/02/03 07:30:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422885720829_0097_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.cognizant.pr2.TroubleMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.cognizant.pr2.TroubleMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
        ... 8 more

15/02/03 07:30:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422885720829_0097_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.cognizant.pr2.TroubleMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.cognizant.pr2.TroubleMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
        ... 8 more

15/02/03 07:30:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422885720829_0097_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.cognizant.pr2.TroubleMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.cognizant.pr2.TroubleMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
        ... 8 more

15/02/03 07:30:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/02/03 07:30:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1422885720829_0097 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1422885720829_0097_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/02/03 07:30:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 6
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=8357
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0

Comment: I tried to run the MR code which is used to load the data from hdfs textfile to hbase table, but it was getting the error as shown above: "Mapper class not found exception" .While  I am running the Mr code , I am passing the jar file , input path, output path, hbase table as arguments ... Plz hlp me I am strucked with this issue from two days, I used the suggestion like:" job.setJarByClass(TroubleDriver.class);"

Comment: You were likely missing setJarByClass. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312088/578101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-compile your java code and make sure you have all jars existing to run mr jobs.

```
"su - hdfs" 

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hbase classpath`

#### export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/*:jar
```

and run MR code!

Comment: Thank you Ali for your support

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this issue like we can place the jar directly under this path:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce directory and run the cmd from this path itself. Now It will be able to access the required one's. I hope it will be helpful. Thank you every one :-)

Comment: You can try this way when you have admin access but this is not the legitimate way. By this way, you can just test your code.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below Driver class Code to resolve this Problem.

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    Job job=Job.getInstance(conf, "MavenSample");

    ***job.setJarByClass(DriverClass.class);***

    job.setMapperClass(MapperClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReducerClass.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));         

    return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;

}
```