# I don't understand setJarByClass in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

Can you explain the setJarByClass method in Hadoop to me?
I don't understand why we have to set a job using a JAR. What's the meaning of this procedure? Why do we need to identify a job by a JAR?

I read other answers:

[Hadoop query regarding setJarByClass method of Job class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912267/hadoop-query-regarding-setjarbyclass-method-of-job-class)

[setJarByClass() in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973532/setjarbyclass-in-hadoop)

But it's still not clear to me.